# SATA SSD in Dell Server

Tags: ssd, dell-poweredge, sata, sas

I have a [Dell R815 (PDF LINK)](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/pedge_r815_specsheet_new.pdf), which has 6 2.5" bays. I would like to put some Intel X25-E in the spare bays, but have been cautioned that they may not fit since they are SATA and the bays are SAS/proprietary.

On the R815 data sheet it says "Up to Six 2.5” hot-swappable SAS, SATA, or SSD drives".

Can I be sure the X25-E will fit?  If not, how am I supposed to use these X25?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need drive enclosures from Dell, but SATA devices connect to SAS controllers without problems. I've used X25-E in Dell R600 systems before.

Comment: I thought that dell has changed the firmware of their raid devices to only allow dell branded / approved devices in their arrays?

Comment: @Chris - Drat, you are right.  I have the PERC H700 - http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/906/t/19314432.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Link: http://www.anandtech.com/show/3894/server-clash-dellr815/6